# Zend Framework 2: Using multiple routes with multiple modules

Tags: php, configuration, module, routes, zend-framework2

I use two modules in my zend framework 2 application:

- Module A
- Module B

I encounter the problem that I can only use **one** of the routes that I have configured for the corresponding module. The route that is used, depends on the sorting of the modules in the **application.config.php** file:

```
<?php
return array(
    'modules' => array(
        'ModuleA','ModuleB'
    );
?>
```

Every module contains nearly the same configuration **module.config.php**:

```
<?php
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'ModuleA' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/moduleA',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'ModuleA\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => false,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'moduleA-index' => array(
                            'type' => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/index[/:action]',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'index',
                                'action' => 'index'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Current situation:

- URL /moduleA routes to /ModuleA/Index/Index
- URL /moduleB routes to /**ModuleA**/Index/Index

Expected:

- URL /moduleA routes to /ModuleA/Index/Index
- URL /moduleB routes to /**ModuleB**/Index/Index

Do you have any advice for me how to use both configurations/routes in the right way?

Comment: Seems there's some sort of ambiguity in your routing configuration. We're going to need to see the actual routes for both modules to see what it is.

Comment: Routes should have unique names. If a Module is supposed to overwrite the configuration of another Module, it's a common best practice to only do this by changing the module load order. Fiddling around with priorities can lead to some very undesired chaining effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `'controller' => 'index',` in your moduleB config too?

if yes then there is your problem `index` is on alias and only **1** controller can have that alias, in other words alias's should be unique throw out the Application and not just a module.

define a unique name(alias) for your controller and you will be fine.

in my project i just use the FQN so there is no confusion (`Namespace\Controller\ControllerName`)

Answer (score 0):

Just add **'priority' param**

```
<?php
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'ModuleA' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'priority' => 100,            // <-- priority
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/moduleA',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'ModuleA\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'may_terminate' => false,
                    'child_routes' => array(
                        'moduleA-index' => array(
                            'type' => 'Segment',
                            'options' => array(
                                'route' => '/index[/:action]',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'index',
                                'action' => 'index'
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```